# Projects similar to google books

Tags: search, text-search, ebooks, metadata, books

Are there other projects similar to google books that allow (legally defensible) search, snippet view, and/or metadata exploration of non-public domain books?

Comment: This would probably be more suited to our [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) sister site

Comment: If you post there, don't forget to delete this question. S.E frowns on duplicates ;-) Good luck